# Plot histogram of a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a very long list of IDs (IDs are string values.
I want to plot a histogram of this list. There are some codes in other threads on stackoverflow for plotting a histogram but the histogram I want should look like this picture (i.e. highest values are in the left side and the values gradually decrease when x-axis increase.

This is the code for plotting regular histogram

```
import pandas
from collections import Counter
items=a long list of strings
letter_counts = Counter(items)
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(letter_counts, orient='index')
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: The histogram]

Comment: are you asking about how to read in the data into something `matplotlib` can read or how to format the histogram once you've read the data and converted it to numerical values?

Comment: @Aaron I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something along these lines...

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

counts = Counter(['a','a','a','c','a','a','c','b','b','d', 'd','d','d','d','b'])
common = counts.most_common()
labels = [item[0] for item in common]
number = [item[1] for item in common]
nbars = len(common)

plt.bar(np.arange(nbars), number, tick_label=labels)
plt.show()
```

The [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) call is the main innovation of this script. The rest is easily found in the `matplotlib` documentation (already linked in my comment).

Comment: `pyplot` has tons of options to make your graph look as pretty as you wish. The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) has some really nice examples with source code as well.

Comment: most_common() removes some elements. For example the original list contains 345000 elements but most_common() returns 43000 elements

Comment: Counter subclasses dicts, so you can do:
```
labels = list(counts.keys());
number = list(counts.values())
```

Comment: @HimanUCC the whole idea of using `Counter` is to reduce the number of elements. `most_common()` is returning a list of tuples containing each element and how many times it occurred. If there are any identical elements at all, the list returned by `most_common` will naturally be shorter than the input list.

Comment: @story645 `counts.keys()` would not preserve the order generated from `most_common()`, which is important if you want the largest columns on the left